# Using BLAS in Alpine Linux

Tags: package-management, arm, alpine-linux

I am running Alpine Linux inside Termux using proot.

I installed `gcc`, `libc-dev` and `openblas`, and tried to compile a C program requiring `cblas.h`.

But it gives the following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/armv6-alpine-linux-musleabihf/8.3.0/../../../../armv6-alpine-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas         
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statusmake: *** [Makefile:8: time_of_pendulum.exe] Error 1
```

The same code has worked in Ubuntu, with the pakcage `libopenblas-dev` installed.

Comment: If you needed the development package `libopenblas-dev` on Ubuntu, why aren't you using the same on Apline? The error's pretty obvious, isn't it (`ld: cannot find -lblas`)?

Comment: There is no package called `libopenblas-dev` or `libblas-dev` in alpine. I installed `lapack-dev`, which has cblas.h but it gave another error (`/usr/lib/gcc/armv6-alpine-linux-musleabihf/8.3.0/../../../../armv6-alpine-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: ode.c:(.text+0x940): undefined reference to `cblas_daxpy'` while `cblas_daxpy` is a standard function in BLAS)

Comment: You probably need a linker flag, of the form `-lsomething`, added to your compilation command. For example, if I want to use something from `math.h` I need the `-lm` linker flag : `gcc -o myprog myprog.c -lm` . I don't have any experience with openblas, but I think the docs will tell you what linker flag you need to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the linker `-lcblas` solved it. However, `lcblas` does not work in Ubuntu.

Previously I used `-lblas`, which worked in Debian and Ubuntu, but failed in Alpine

Comment: The correct flags to use would be returned by `pkg-config --cflags --libs openblas`.

Answer (score 4):

You would probably also need to install the development libraries of `openblas`, just as you did on the Ubuntu system:

```
apk add openblas-dev
```

[Alpine maintains an extensive package search tool](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openblas*&branch=v3.10) that can help find out if packages are split into multiples.

Comment: I have installed both `openblas-dev` and `openblas`, but it does not work.

Comment: I just noticed that you have an `armv6-alpine` build, [make sure your hardware is supported by Alpine](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_on_ARM) and your software is compatible with `musl` which replaces `glibc`.  Without seeing the code that will not build, I would be unable to provide further assistance.

Comment: Sure, this is the code - https://github.com/apandada1/physics-simulations/tree/master/Pendulum%20time%20period . Run `make` to compile. And, my mobile phone runs Qualcom Snapdragon 210 MSm8909, which is not listed on that webpage. I installed Alpine from this link https://github.com/Hax4us/TermuxAlpine. Alpine runs, only BLAS does not seem to work.

Comment: This solved another problem that I had with opencv-python missing cblas_dgemm.